Can I still help Grace Pinch-Smedley to retrieve something from the lake later in the game if I say no to her the first time?
I'm at the place where I meet Grace Pinch-Smedley and she has a side quest for me where she asked me to help her retrieve something from the bottom of the lake.

I've been given two choices that basically come down to the following:
Yes:

An underwater adventure sounds like fun.

No:

Diving into the lake doesn't sound too appealing.


Now, I want to help her, but not right now, but I'm afraid if I say no to her now, that I won't have the opportunity to do it in the future.
What are the consequences of each choice? Would I be able to talk to her again and help her later if I say no now?

Shaun, in Hogwarts Legacy, side quests often give you the flexibility to come back to them later if you initially decline. If you tell Grace Pinch-Smedley that "Diving into the lake doesn't sound too appealing," you should still be able to return and accept the quest at a later time.
Saying "No" will allow you to decline the quest for now and return to it later when you are ready. Saying "Yes" lets you take on the quest immediately. There are no major consequences in terms of story or character relationships, so you can decide based on your current priorities and readiness to take on the quest.
So, if you prefer not to help Grace right now, you can safely decline and revisit her later to accept the quest.

Don't forget that you can accept now but do it later anyway.
